# Any open source java library which can parse an EDI file in both ANSI x12 and UN/EDIFACT standards?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, java-ee-5, edi

Is there any open source java library which can parse an EDI file in both **ANSI X12** and **UN/EDIFACT** standards? I have found **smooks** (http://www.smooks.org), which supports UN/EDIFACT standard but not sure whether this will support EDI files in ANSI X12 standard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Smooks team publish their future release would start supporting the X12 version.I eagerly waiting here too.

Answer (score 1):

According documentation [EDIReader](http://edireader.sourceforge.net/) can parse both ANSI X12 and UN/EDIFACT.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used X12 Java parser. Here is the link http://code.google.com/p/x12-parser/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to take a look at [StAEDI](https://github.com/xlate/staedi), a streaming parser/generator that supports X12 and EDIFACT with schema validation. Disclaimer: I am the author of the library.