# How to parse EDI 837 file in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, edi, x12

Is there any java code for parsing this  EDI 837 file format.Anyone here  can tell me how to parse this file .

i have tried this but it is for  EDI 835 :

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/x12-parser/latest/x12-parser.pdf

```
**strong text**   ISA*03*          *00*          *ZZ*P4888          *01*330897513      *160709*0256*^*00501*141000000*1*P*:~GS*HC*P4888*330897513*20160709*0256*141*X*005010X222A1~ST*837*0001*005010X222A1~BHT*0019*00*0001*20160709*0256*CH~NM1*41*2*ererwr*****46*P4888~PER*IC*deditrt Companies*TE*3053968271*FX*3053968271~NM1*40*2*330897513*****46*330897513~HL*1**20*1~PRV*BI*PXC*282NC0060X~NM1*85*2*ABC*****XX*1205886280~N3*5429 College Drive~N4*Graceville*FL*324401858~REF*EI*596139709~HL*2*1*22*0~SBR*P*18*******ZZ~NM1*IL*1*swain*sitansu*sekhar***MI*1234~N3*123~N4*banglor*DC*75424~DMG*D8*20160703*M~NM1*PR*2*ghfhg*****PI*9999~N3*PO BOX 741107~N4*HOUSTON*TX*77274~CLM*147*2427.50***81:B:1*Y*A*Y*Y~HI*ABK:F0390~NM1*DN*1*Ligotti*Michael****XX*Ligotti~NM1*82*1*JohNMike*John****XX*12121212~NM1*77*2*SR4*****N3~N4~LX*1~SV1*HC:80053*126.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*155~LX*2~SV1*HC:80061*160.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*156~LX*3~SV1*HC:81003*30.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*157~LX*4~SV1*HC:84436*82.50*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*158~LX*5~SV1*HC:84443*201.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*159~LX*6~SV1*HC:84479*77.50*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*160~LX*7~SV1*HC:84480*170.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*161~LX*8~SV1*HC:85025*92.50*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*162~LX*9~SV1*HC:87086*96.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*163~LX*10~SV1*HC:80048*101.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*164~LX*11~SV1*HC:80061*160.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*165~LX*12~SV1*HC:82306*355.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*166~LX*13~SV1*HC:82607*181.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*167~LX*14~SV1*HC:82746*176.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*168~LX*15~SV1*HC:84443*201.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*169~LX*16~SV1*HC:84450*61.25*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*170~LX*17~SV1*HC:84460*62.50*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*171~LX*18~SV1*HC:85025*92.50*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160704-20160704~REF*6R*172~HL*3**20*1~PRV*BI*PXC*282NC0060X~NM1*85*2*cvcv-dfdf*****XX*1205886280~N3*5429 College Drive~N4*Graceville*FL*324401858~REF*EI*596139709~HL*4*3*22*0~SBR*P*18*******ZZ~NM1*IL*1*swain*sitansu*sekhar***MI*1234~N3*123~N4*banglor*DC*75424~DMG*D8*20160703*M~NM1*PR*2*heuyuyu*****PI*9999~N3*PO BOX 741107~N4*HOUSTON*TX*77274~CLM*141*120.00***81:B:1*Y*A*Y*Y~REF*F8*123~HI*ABK:F0390*ABF:F1020~NM1*DN*1*Ligotti*Michael****XX*Ligotti~NM1*82*1*JohNMike*John****XX*12121212~NM1*77*2*SR41*****N3~N4~LX*1~SV1*HC:12001*120.00*UN*1*81**1:2~DTP*472*RD8*20160703-20160703~REF*6R*144~HL*5**20*1~PRV*BI*PXC*282NC0060X~NM1*85*2*vbvfgfgg*****XX*1205886280~N3*5429 College Drive~N4*fhfh*FL*324401858~REF*EI*596139709~HL*6*5*22*0~SBR*P*18*******ZZ~NM1*IL*1*test*test*test***MI*3333~N3*test~N4*test*AS*11111~DMG*D8*20160630*M~NM1*PR*2*fdf PPO MEDICAL*****PI*9999~N3*PO BOX 742567~N4*dfdf*TX*77274~CLM*140*20.00***81:B:1*Y*A*Y*Y~HI*ABK:F1120~NM1*DN*1*asasas*asasas*asasas***XX*asasas~NM1*82*1*erer*John****XX*12121212~NM1*77*2*SR4*****N3~N4~LX*1~SV1*HC:99202*20.00*UN*1*81**1~DTP*472*RD8*20160630-20160630~REF*6R*141~SE*150*0001~GE*1*141~IEA*1*141000000~
```

Thanks

Sitansu

Comment: Through google I see that this is a Standard file format for health care claims, right? I guess there should be an official documentation on this format available. But it could be that it is not freely ( in the meaning of free of charge ) available.

Comment: @Fildor is there any source code for this parse

Comment: I do not have source code. You need to look for the documentation. I would have posted a link if I had seen one on the spot. Hence my suspicion it could be "payed content".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816836/any-open-source-java-library-which-can-parse-an-edi-file-in-both-ansi-x12-and-un may help

Comment: X12 spec is not freely available like @Fildor mentioned.

Comment: I know this is a late reply, But I worked in same EDI x12 messages of multiple numbers through an opensource tool called Mirthconnect. You can give a try in it. It's free and easy, Parsing will be handled mostly by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this repo.  Be mindful that this is still work in progress. 837 is a message on the milestone.
https://github.com/xiaoerge/X12Healthcare